# How can I write an C++ HTML5 application in PNaCl without any JavaScript knowledge?

Tags: c++, html, google-nativeclient

I'm a C++ programmer and I want to write an application purely in C++ and HTML5 and CSS without any knowledge of JavaScript with the help of Portable Native Client. I am not intended to learn JavaScript either. Is this possible?

Comment: If time is not a constraint, I highly recommend you reconsider learning javascript.  If you can program c++ well, javascript will come easily.  jQuery will come even easier.

Comment: No, I want to program for web purely in C++. Is this possible?

Comment: Wt can generate client side code, but it won't be as flexible.  I don't know of any other c++ that generates client side code.  Also, you may have trouble finding supporting libraries for more specific frameworks like google nativeclient.  Again, you'll be shocked at how quickly you'll pick up html5 especially if you use jquery libraries like json2html to do all of the heavy lifting.  With that lib alone, my client lines have dropped to a negligible amount. http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt

Comment: No, I want to generate HTML5 elements from portable native client with Pepper API. How can I do that?

Comment: Hmm, I think you might have to find a way to fuse Wt & Pepper, but I'm sorry I don't have enough experience with Pepper to help much further.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for NaCl/PNaCl C/C++ to effect the DOM is by passing messages to JavaScript (using postMessage()) and having JavaScript perform the DOM actions required.

The only way for C/C++ to render directly is to use the 2D or 3D canvas APIs.